# Rails 'DB - no such column' error for has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many, nested-attributes

I created a `has_many :through` relationship for a rails app I am creating. However, I am unable have nested attributes for the many to many relationship.

My models are as follows:

**article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :title
  has_many :article_tags
  has_many :tags, :through => :article_tags, :foreign_key => :tag_id    
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, reject_if: :all_blank    
  attr_accessible :tags_attributes    
  validates_presence_of [:body, :title]
end
```

**tag.rb:**

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :article_tags
   has_many :articles, :through => :article_tags, :foreign_key => :article_id
   attr_accessible :name
   validates_presence_of :name

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :articles, reject_if: :all_blank

   attr_accessible :articles_attributes
end
```

**article_tag.rb:**

```
class ArticleTag < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :article
 belongs_to :tag
end
```

Now in my view for the article (show.html.slim), I want to show all tags that belong to the article using the line:

```
- @article.tags.each do |t|
  = t.name
```

However, I get the error:
`SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: article_tags.article_id: SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "article_tags" ON "tags"."id" = "article_tags"."tag_id" WHERE "article_tags"."article_id" = 1`

This problem is solved.

For anybody who needs to know:

You must **manually** add the foreign keys in the migration and the schema. I added them and voila! it works!

Thanks to Dan Reedy for his help!

Answer (score 2):

Your `ArticleTag` class is incorrect. The `belongs_to` associations should be singular.

```
class ArticleTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I made the change, but now the error has changed to a DB error

Comment: Could you post the database schema for the `article_tags` table? The foreign keys should be `article_id` and `tag_id` but I'm guessing you have the plural form.

Comment: I will dan however I am a newbie, which file is the schema for the article_tags table? do you mean the migration?

Comment: Either the migration or the `article_tags` section of `db/schema.rb`

Comment: The `article_tags` schema only has `created_at` and `updated_at` fields:

Answer (score 1):

You must use `has_and_belongs_to_many` in this situation.